# How to find the max of each row in a table in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by, max

I have this table below which has N rows. here i simplify it to 3 rows.

Example Table

```
        A                   B                   C                      D
5.640700669769904   5.623475843268976   5.644739934022418
5.62489798487818    5.581388826442135   5.62376476667017
5.62708139972593    5.606610562903928   5.592366625377977
```

i need to find the new column D which consists of the maximum of the row for columns A,B,C.

in MYSQL MAX(X) only applies to the column. How would i solve this problem?

I have tried with sub tables but no luck.

Comment: "I have tried with sub tables but no luck"  So where is it????  I don't see any code.

Comment: Can you have `NULL` values in the columns?

Comment: No null values in the columns. No.

Comment: This kind of problem is highly symptomatic of poor or flawed schema design

Comment: Interesting.  Can you elaborate on this? I am not sure I understand what you mean by that. The original columns A, B, C cannot be collapse into one initially.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`max()` is an aggregate functions that operates over values that are store across rows (although some databases, namely SQLite, allows using it for list of values).

You can use `greatest()` to get the greatest value over the three columns on each row:

```
select t.*, greatest(a, b, c) d from mytable
```

On the other hand, if you want the greatest value over all 3 columns *and all rows*, you can use both `max()` and `greatest()` together:

```
select max(greatest(a, b, c)) overall_greatest from mytable
```